# Question on Galilean transformation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory, galilean-relativity

Let $a$ be a scalar, $D$ a rotation matrix and $b$ and $v$ are $1\times 3$-vectors.

We had the following [Galiean transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation):

$(t, x(t)) \to (t + a, Dx + b + v\cdot t)$

But why is it not

$(t, x(t)) \to (t + a, Dx(t+a) + b + v\cdot (t+a))$

Or are both equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are confusing how the Galilean transformations act. There are three main subset of the Galilean transformations:

Translations: ${g_1(a,b);g_1(a,b)(t,x)=(t+a,x+b)}$,

Rotations: ${g_2(D);g_2(D)(t,x)=(t,Dx)}$,

Boosts: ${g_3(v);g_3(v)(t,x)=(t,x+vt)}$.

Note that we do not write $x$ as a function of time, it is a completely independent coordinate.

You are doing transformations in the following way, **which is not correct**,

$$g_3(v)g_1(a,b)g_2(D)(t,x)=g_3(v)g_1(a,b)(t,Dx(t))=g_3(v)(t+a,Dx(t+a)+b)=(t+a,Dx(t+a)+b+vt),$$

$$g_1(a,b)g_3(v)g_2(D)(t,x)=g_1(a,b)g_3(v)(t,Dx(t))=g_3(v)(t,Dx(t)+vt)=(t+a,Dx(t+a)+v(t+a)+b).$$

**The correct is**
$$g_3(v)g_1(a,b)g_2(D)(t,x)=g_3(v)g_1(a,b)(t,Dx)=g_3(v)(t+a,Dx+b)=(t+a,Dx+b+vt),$$

$$g_1(a,b)g_3(v)g_2(D)(t,x)=g_1(a,b)g_3(v)(t,Dx)=g_3(v)(t,Dx+vt)=(t+a,Dx+vt+b).$$

Boosts and translations commute. The order only matters with respect to rotations.

Comment: In the example above it does not matter. But compute $g_1g_2(t,x)$ and $g_2g_1(t,x)$ and you will see that the order matters.

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. I'm still not quiet sure, why the first notation is not correct. Could you elucidate?

Comment: The variable $x$ you are transforming is a coordinate such as $t$. You cannot think of $x$ as a curve $x(t)$ parametrized by time. When you translate time, there is no translation in $x$. Note that when you translate position you also do not translate time because you are not viewing t as $t(x)$. They are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically there is no difference, just call $\tilde{{\bf b}} = {\bf b} + a{\bf v}$, and you get the same form of the transformation